# PictureBox makes white parts transparent itself

Tags: c#, picturebox, transparent

My picturebox acts like it is .PNG file.

It makes white parts transparent.

Even penetrates "Form" and i'm able to see what's behind Form *(like my desktop, files)*.

But it seems normal in Form1.cs [Design].

```
//card properties and design
this.card.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
this.card.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("card.BackgroundImage")));
this.card.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
this.card.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(47, 92);
this.card.Name = "card";
this.card.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 157);
this.card.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.card.TabIndex = 2;
this.card.TabStop = false;
this.card.Visible = false;
```

Here is a picture of without running:

[image: Here is a picture of without running]

Second picture that explains what's my problem:

[image: Second picture that explains what's my problem]

Comment: is the png image transparent?

Comment: do you have a transparency key set on your form?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Oh, I deleted transparency key line from Designer.cs it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a `TransparencyKey` being set to `Color.White`. Try clearing that.